# Define global config values for plotly's Figure show method

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

A plotly `Figure` has `show()` method which accepts a `config` argument, as per [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 1]))

fig.show(config=config)
```

This can be quite tedious, as I have to catch the Figure and show it with the `show` method instead of normal usage.

Instead of just doing

```
px.line(df)
```

Now I have to

```
fig = px.line(df)
fig.show(config=config)
```

In all charts.
Is there a way through the Plotly library to define the config values globally, so that I can call `px.line` without setting the config per `Figure` instance, and I dont have to create a custom wrapper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: Turn off modebar for the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648403/plotly-turn-off-modebar-for-the-session)

Comment: The method there solves the problem but my question is generic and that question is more specific. Should that be a duplicate of this or it doesnt matter?

Comment: How is this question generic?

Comment: That question asks how to change one setting of the config object. This question is about the config object itself.

Comment: It's the same attribute on the renderers.