# Plotly: Turn off modebar for the session

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I can turn off the modebar in plotly by passing `displayModeBar: False` as the value of `config` in `fig.show()`, like this-

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y='GOOG')

fig.show(config={'displayModeBar':False})
```

But is there a way I could do it just once for the entire session rather than having to pass it with each figure call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers['jupyterlab'].config['displayModeBar'] = False
```

Comment: I just tried this. It does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Do you use Jupyter Lab? There are a few other environments: notebook, kaggle, colab - you can inspect them via `pio.renderers` and modify the line above accordingly.

Comment: Amazing! It works now, I was using jupyter notebook so I changed the key to `notebook`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this there isn't an official way to set a default `config` value for the `show` function of every figure.

What I would recommend as a workaround is to create a function that sets default values and passes them on to the `show` function of a figure:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()


def show(fig, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.get("config", {}).setdefault("displayModeBar", False)
    fig.show(*args, **kwargs)


df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="GOOG")
show(fig)
```

The above sets the default value of `config` to `{"displayModeBar": False}`. The default value can simply be overwritten by passing arguments to the custom `show` function.